# PartialView is not updating with new data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

By default I am loading all data inside partial view

**html code in Index.cshtml**

```
@model GMWUI.ViewModel.MessageDisplayModel

<div id="divTblMsg" class="grid-content">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("filterMessages", Model);
    }
</div>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        messageDisplayModel.Messages = await ApiClientFactory.Instance.GetMessages();

        return View(messageDisplayModel);
    }
```

when user click on filter button with search criteria
I am getting filtered data from web api to my home controller filtermessage method

**here is my ajax call when I click filter button**

```
     $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: "Home/postMessage",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //my table element id is divTblMsg
                $("#divTblMsg").html(data);
            }
        });
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> filterMessages(GetMessageParams searchCriteria)
        {
            //I though adding below line will clear old data should update partial view with filtered data, but it is not working.
            messageDisplayModel.Messages = Enumerable.Empty<Messages>(); 
            messageDisplayModel.Messages = await ApiClientFactory.Instance.GetMessages(searchCriteria);
         //I am getting filtered data to messageDisplayModel.messages and I am passing it to partial view 
            return PartialView("filterMessages", messageDisplayModel.Messages);
        }
```

I was unable to find the issue

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? If you set a breakpoint at the line of code where you are returning the PartialView, is it hitting that breakpoint, and is the Messages variable populated?

Comment: Could you add the controller method postMessage to the homecontroller.cs source in your question

Answer (score 2):

Is it by chance because your AJAX method is `post`ing to `Home/postMessage` and not `get`ing from `filterMessages` which you have marked with an `[HttpGet]` filter?

Comment: I have updated my ajax call with "get" but it is not working

Comment: You also changed the `url` value too? Is the network log in your browser showing any errors or responses?

Comment: the response status is 200 and view is loading with updated HTML  in preview and response tab in browser developer tools network section 
but my partial view is still showing old data

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by updating my ajax call as follows.

```
       $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("filterMessages", "Home")',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: model,
        dataType: 'HTML',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divTblMsg").html(data);
        }
    });
```

I have updated **Method to Get** as I am using Get attribute for my action result and updated **url** and **dataType to HTML because the response that we will get is in HTML**.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing URL path to match exactly as controller action name, and the method type equals to attribute set on that action:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET', // or type: 'GET'
    url: '@Url.Action("filterMessages", "Home")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ searchCriteria: model }), // here you should include action parameter name
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#divTblMsg").html(data);
    }
});
```

If you want to use `POST` method, simply replace `[HttpGet]` with `[HttpPost]` and follow the URL convention as shown above.

Also take note that you should make sure that passed `model` contains object (an object defined like `var model = {};`) and then assign values for `model` properties.

Comment: View is loading in network tab browser developer tools in google chrome but it is not displaying in UI 
Grid is still showing old data in UI